# SUSE 12 service cleanup

Tags: linux, suse, sles

I am using a SLES 12 VM where I have installed a service called as `besclient` using an RPM. When I uninstall the agent and remove the files the status of the service still shows ac active. I checked and found these 2 files still remain.

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/besclient.service
/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/besclient.service
```

which I am unable to remove using `rm -rf command`. How to remove these kind of files?

```
rm: cannot remove '/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/besclient.service/tasks': Operation not permitted
```

I am running this as root.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persistent cgroups are released when the unit is disabled and its configuration file is deleted by running:

~]# systemctl disable name.service

where name stands for the name of the service to be disabled.

[Red Hat reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/sec-removing_cgroups)

Apparently something is still running. Try:
`cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/besclient.service/tasks` to see if you can find a process PID.

Comment: `deehdss013ccp:~/chefrepolocalmode # cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/besclient.service/pids.current
0
`

Comment: This is after disabling the service. Also when I check status of the service

service besclient status
â besclient.service - Besclient Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/besclient.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-05-15 12:27:13 UTC; 2h 17min ago
 Main PID: 10687 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/besclient.service

May 15 12:27:13 deehdss013ccp systemd[1]: Started Besclient Daemon.
May 15 12:30:15 deehdss013ccp systemd[1]: Started Besclient Daemon.

Comment: Try `systemd-cgls`

Comment: No output `systemd-cgls | grep bes`

Comment: Did you try a `systemctl daemon-reload`?

Answer (score 0):

The `/sys` filesystem provides [a filesystem-like view on information and config settings of the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720471). I.e., these are not "really" files, that is why you cannot delete them.